# php string manipulation similar to C

Tags: php

I need to send this form of data :

```
 $objectData = '{"userid":"abc", "action":"def","data":"data"}';
```

I have the vars already :

```
$userID=htmlspecialchars($_GET["userid"]);
$action=htmlspecialchars($_GET["action"]);
$data=htmlspecialchars($_GET["data"]);
```

How should i create `$objectData` with these fields inside(userid/action/data)?

Something similar i know (OBJ-C) `[stringWithFormat:" %@, %d", "a", 5 ];`

Comment: Why complicate things, can't you use normal PHP string concatenation?

Comment: or you can build an array, and jsonencode it.

Comment: FYI, the use of `htmlspecialchars` is unnecessary/misplaced/abused/wrong here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you want to create a json string.
You can use `stdClass();` to create an empty object and use `json_encode()` to make it a json string.

```
$objectData = new stdClass();
$objectData->userid = $userID;
$objectData->action = $action;
$objectData->data = $data;
$objectData = json_encode($objectData);
```

Answer (score 3):

That is JSON, produce it with [`json_encode`](http://php.net/json_encode).

```
echo json_encode([
    'userid' => $_GET['userid'],
    'action' => $_GET['action'],
    'data'   => $_GET['data']
]);
```

Or simply:

```
echo json_encode($_GET);
```

Since, apparently `$_GET` already has the array structure you want.

Answer (score 1):

Form array and then using `json_encode()` you can generate json string

```
<?php

$userID=htmlspecialchars($_GET["userid"]);
$action=htmlspecialchars($_GET["action"]);
$data=htmlspecialchars($_GET["data"]);
$jsonArray = array('userid' => $userID, 'action' => $action, 'data' => $data);

echo json_encode($jsonArray);

// TO DECODE JSON STRING

echo json_decode($jsonbject);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Php you can simply concatenate strings with a dot. Like this:

```
$objectData = '{"userid":"' . $userID . '", "action":"' . $action . '","data":"' . $data . '"}';
```

Comment: While yes, you can do that, it's probably a bad idea to do so, because you're risking producing invalid JSON.

Comment: No denying in that, but this works also when you don't produce JSON.